# Improving random generation function

Tags: java, random

I am doing a small app that involves the system randomly generating objects. Here's how it goes

Each objects has a field that specifies the **"type"** of the object. Let's say fire, ice, wind (not the actual thing in the app though)
Each type has a field called **"possibilities"** that determines the possibilities of that type being generated.
The default value for this field is of course 1/numberOfTypes
Another field of a type is its **"order"** in the list, let's say fire is 1st and ice is 2nd and wind is 3rd.

My naive solution to this is to use 
`Math.floor(Math.random()*100 / defualtPossibilities)` and match it with type.oder
So if the random value is .75, and there are three types, `Math.floor(...)` will `return 2` which means that the object is an ice object.

However, I meet with some potential problems:

1. It is possible to alter the possibilities value of each type. In this case I can still generate a random number and use a loop to check each **type.order*type.possibilities** until it exceeds the random number. But I'm not sure whether there's a better way of doing it.
2. When you change one **type.possibilities**, the other **type. possibilities** must change in accordance to keep the total possibilities 100. I plan to do this by divide evenly the amount of change to all the other types. Is it a good approach.

I'm sorry if I'm vague at some points but please help me ^-^

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you want to generate random string or random number or alfanumeric number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short solution :

```
 float weights[]; // each >0

 public int nextIndex() {     
     float sum =0;
     for (int i=weights.length; i-->0;) sum+=weights[i];
     float r = myrandom.nextFloat()*sum;
     sum = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<weights.length-1; i++) {
         sum += weights[i];
         if (r<sum) return i;
     }
     return weights.length-1;
 }
```

You can change each weight independently. The idea is simply to recompute the sum of the weights instead of supposing it's 100.

Obviously, for the best performances you could precompute the sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It really helps simplifying my problem. I see now how silly I was trying to keep the sum 100. This idea of keeping the sum 100 comes from my idea of implementing a meter whose total length is constant while the component lengths may change accordingly. Now I see I can keep this feature without having a constant 100. Thanks again!